# exporting table records as insert in mysql using mysql query browser?

Tags: mysql

how to export table records as insert in mysql using mysql query browser?

is there any other tool that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old school way is to use string concatenation:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES(', t.col1,',', t.col2, ')')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Copy the output to a script.  Mind that you'll have to handle data types appropriately (IE date/time).

But I have to wonder why you don't just use mysqldump, and get the INSERT statement out of the per table backup.

Comment: @sam: I forgot a bracket, try now.

Answer (score 5):

You might use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility if you have access to it.  An example might be

```
C:\mydir> mysqldump <database> -u<username> -p<password> -t -n -c <table>
```

Comment: in C:\Xampp\MYSQL\BIN, I run mysql -u root then did this: mysql> mysqldump -u test -p test –all-databases > dump.sql; this didnt work

Comment: @sam - Sorry, answer is not clear enough - run mysqldump _instead of_ mysql.